# Reverse then print a string in x86

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, reverse, irvine32

I am trying to figure out how to reverse a string into a new location and then print it.

I know that I have to loop through the string, push each character into a stack and then pop back into the same string, but after that, I am slightly confused.

I came up with the following code, but because I have issues understanding the register window in Visual Studio, I decided to try using the WriteString function. However, it doesn't seem to load the window.

Am I calling WriteString incorrectly?

---

Also, for what it's worth, when I tried "jumping over", the loops do loop the appropriate amount of times, although L2 only shows "d" when I'm watching it, and L3 only shows "s".

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.386
.stack 4096
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

.data
str1 BYTE "dogs"
rStr BYTE 4 DUP(?)  ;reverse

.code
main proc

mov ecx, 4
mov esi,0

L1: mov al, str1[esi]
mov rStr[esi], al
inc esi
Loop L1 


L2: movzx eax, rStr[esi]
push eax
inc esi
Loop L2

mov ecx, 4
mov esi,0

L3: pop eax
mov rStr[esi],al
inc esi
Loop L3

mov edx,OFFSET rStr
call WriteString 

exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: *I know that I have to loop through the string, push each character into a stack and then pop back into the same string*.  That's one way, but you definitely don't *have* to do it that way.  You could just copy directly instead of to the stack and back, incrementing one pointer and decrementing another.

Comment: *the loops do loop the appropriate amount of times* That seems unlikely, since you don't write ECX after the end of `loop L1` leaves ECX=0 on entry to `L2:`.  Learn to use your debugger.

Comment: @PeterCordes so after loop L1 and loop L2 I have to rewrite ECX?

Comment: Well really you should just get rid of L1 entirely, and read from the original string in the loop that pushes.  IDK what the point of copying from str1 to rStr in non-reversed order is.  Anyway, learning to use a debugger will be the most valuable thing you can do with your time.

Comment: Well now they loop 3 times (0,1,2,3), but because I can't seem figure out the debugger now, I have no way of knowing through there if it worked. However, in the second where the debugger screen appears, I see that it returns "sgod", so on the bright side, at least I know it works. Thank you for pointing out about rewriting ECX.

Comment: What's unclear about "register window"? (serious question, I mean that's the most important window while debugging ASM, so you are definitely stuck until you figure that one out) (by the problem with `ecx` it looks like you missed the whole point what CPU register **is**, so I wonder how you got even that far with your code without understanding that one, I'm sort of impressed, can't even imagine how you understand those instructions while programming, if you dare to explain your mental view, I would appreciate it)

Comment: Did you look at the many, many questions that ask (and have answers) related to reversing a string in assembly?